# How do I open a new Terminal window in the same directory as the current window

Tags: terminal

When I have a Terminal window open, ⌘N opens a new one.

Is there any way to get the current directory in the new window to automatically be the same as it was on the window where I pressed ⌘N?

Answer (score 29):

To accomplish this within a new window, go to Preferences within Terminal.app.

Within the General tab, you can adjust the behavior (you likely want to select **Same Working Directory**) for both new windows and new tabs.

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Oh, looks like I already had it enabled but must have messed it up somehow in my .bashrc. Thanks!

Comment: Three years later I found I just had some cd command at the end of said .bashrc, after removing that this started to work.

Comment: @Bemmu Ha. Glad you figured it out - been waiting... ;)

Answer (score 14):

If you hit `⌘T` in the Terminal, it will open another tab, which will be in the same directory as before :-).

You can easily switch between the tabs using keyboard shortcuts too like

`- ⌘-Shift-[ and ⌘-Shift-]`

Enjoy!

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: You can also then drag the tab out to a separate window if you didn't want it tabbed

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. If I change directory in terminal and open a new tab the new tab is not in that directory.

Comment: @smohadjer look at your settings - there should be separate settings for 'New windows open with' and 'New tabs open with' - you can adjust those so that the behavior is more to your liking

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that Terminal doesn't know anything about what directory you're in.

But the shell does! So you can type:

```
open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app .
```

and it will open a new window on your current directory.

If you want to do this a lot, put the following in `~/.bashrc:`

```
alias openhere='open -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app .'
```

Then, all you will have to type is `openhere` to do the same thing.

Comment: Terminal does know your directory. The shell reports to Apple Terminal whenever directory changes; the code that enables this is in `/etc/bashrc`.

Comment: That would be
 `alias openhere='open -a /Systems/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app .' ` 
for Big Sur OS :)

Comment: just `open -a Terminal .` seems to do the trick

Comment: @hamstergene, I don't see anything in my /etc/bashrc that "reports to Apple Terminal" about directory changes. Mine sets a prompt that bash itself updates, and tells bash to change its idea about Terminal directions upon process completion. Or am I missing something?

Comment: iTerm `open -a iTerm .`

Answer (score 5):

In Zshell, I need to do both this setting

[image]

and I need this in my .zshrc

```
# http://superuser.com/a/315029/4952
# Set Apple Terminal.app to resume directory... still necessary 2018-10-26
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "Apple_Terminal" ]] && [[ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]] {
  function chpwd {
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
  }
  chpwd
}
```

I've tried without one or the other to no avail.