# Why does Terminal not honor preferences?

Tags: terminal, command-line, zsh

Sometime in the last week my Terminal stopped honoring the "New tabs open with: Same Working Directory" setting.  Testing with "New windows ..." gave the same result.

My shell is zsh.

**I was able to get this to work** by following an answer here from [Dan Rosenstark](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/18875/dan-rosenstark)
https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/340778/398648

```
# http://superuser.com/a/315029/4952
# Set Apple Terminal.app to resume directory... still necessary 2018-10-26
if [[ $TERM_PROGRAM == "Apple_Terminal" ]] && [[ -z "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]] {
  function chpwd {
    local SEARCH=' '
    local REPLACE='%20'
    local PWD_URL="file://$HOSTNAME${PWD//$SEARCH/$REPLACE}"
    printf '\e]7;%s\a' "$PWD_URL"
  }
  chpwd
}
```

But: **I do not know how I could have determined this for myself, or how I could have debugged a similar problem**.

Any tips or tricks to figure out what those initial steps of Terminal are would be greatly appreciated.

Things that did not work:

- Toggling settings for New Tab or New Window
- Renaming or adding `return` at the first line of `.zshrc`, `.zsh*` files
- All of the suggestions in [Open new Terminal tab in current working directory doesn't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/144896/open-new-terminal-tab-in-current-working-directory-doesnt-work)

Other potentially useful info:

- The "Same Profile"/"Default Profile" settings are honored when changed
- Adding `pwd` as the first line of `.zshrc` shows the directory is already `/home/<myuser>`
- I have installed and uninstalled some tools and projects involving `nix` recently (including `nix-darwin`)

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Metadata:

```
OS        macOS Catalina 10.15.7 (19H2)
Terminal  2.10 (433)
zsh       5.7.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin19.0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on "Escape sequence…" in that screenshot, you get to see the following:

[image]

What this doesn't tell you, though, is that this is normally taken care of in the file `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`, which is called from `/etc/zshrc`. There are several things that can prevent `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` from being called or which can override what it tries to do:

- You are starting Zsh with `zsh -d` or `zsh -f`.
- You have a file `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshenv` or `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zprofile` in which you have `setopt NO_rcs` or `setopt NO_globalrcs`
- The parameter `$TERM_PROGRAM` does not have the value `Apple_Terminal`.
- Zsh does not have read access to `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal`.
- When `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` gets sourced, the parameter `$INSIDE_EMACS` is non-zero.
- You define a function `precmd` sometime *after* `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` gets sourced, which then overrides the one defined by `add-zsh-hook`.

What you can do to debug:

- Start a subshell without non-global config files and see if the bug happens there, too:

  ```
  cd $(mktemp -d); HOME=$PWD ZDOTDIR=$PWD zsh
  ```

  If the problem does not occur in this subshell, then that means the problem is somewhere in your non-global dotfiles. You can get a list of these files by doing

  ```
  ls ${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.z(log(in|out)|profile|sh(env|rc))(-^/)
  ```
- Restart Zsh with `exec zsh -vx` and study the output from the beginning to see if `/etc/zshrc_Apple_Terminal` gets sourced and whether anything later overrides the `precmd` hook it sets up.

Comment: All I could have hoped for in a response, I learned a lot.  Thank you!